# NN vs Greedy Search

Tags: algorithm, knn, greedy

Both NN and Greedy Search algorithms have a `Greed` nature, and both have tendency towards the lowest cost/distance (my understanding may be incorrect though). But what makes them different in a way that each one can be classified into a distinct algorithm group is somehow unclear to me.

For instance, if I can solve a particular problem using NN, I can surely solve it with Greedy Search algorithm as well specially if minimization is the case. I came to this conclusion because when I start coding them I come across very similar implementations in code although the general concept behind both might be different. Sometimes I can't even tell if the implementation follows NN or Greedy Search.

I have done my homework well and searched enough on Google, but couldn't find a decent explanation on what distinguishes them from one another. Any such explanation is indeed appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, at a very high level they both driven by heuristics in order to evaluate a given solution against an ideal solution. But, whilst a greedy search algo outputs a solution for a given input, the NN trains a model that will generate solutions for given inputs. So at a very very high level, you can think that the NN generates a solution finder, whereas the greedy search is a harcoded solution finder.

Comment: In other words, the NN will generate "code" (i.e. the model) that finds solutions to the problem. The greedy search is you actually writing the code that finds the solution to the problem. This is quite wishy washy though, I'm sure there is a much more concise, academically sound way of expressing what I've just said

Comment: All of what I've just said in based on the assumption that by "Greedy search" you meant the algorithms to solve problems such as travelling sales man

Comment: @ThomasCook: I don't agree that Greedy would be a hardcoded solution while NN would be not, because I can go for NN without creating a train set and directly go for the output. I appreciate if you explain more.

Comment: @ThomasCook: If you move your comments into an answer, it will surely receive my upvote and may finally be accepted.

Comment: Sure, I've done that. I was hesitant to post an answer as I don't think it covers all the bases (and I'm sure someone with far more algorithmic knowledge than myself will crap all over it).

Comment: @Arrrr: the [tag:knn] tag is presumably a mistake?

Comment: @Groo: No, I actually tagged it on purpose, because by NN I actually mean the KNN implementation. I could not not find an NN tag.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, at a very high level they both driven by heuristics in order to evaluate a given solution against an ideal solution. But, whilst a greedy search algo outputs a solution for a given input, the NN trains a model that will generate solutions for given inputs. So at a very very high level, you can think that the NN generates a solution finder, whereas the greedy search is a harcoded solution finder.

In other words, the NN will generate "code" (i.e. the model (aka the weights)) that finds solutions to the problem when provided to the same network topology. The greedy search is you actually writing the code that finds the solution to the problem. This is quite wishy washy though, I'm sure there is a much more concise, academically sound way of expressing what I've just said

All of what I've just said in based on the assumption that by "Greedy search" you meant the algorithms to solve problems such as travelling sales man.

Another way to think of it is:

In greedy search, you write an algorithm that solves a search problem (find me the graph that best describes the relationship, based on provided heuristic(s), between data point A and data point B).

When you write a neural network, you declare a network topology, provide some initially "random" weights and some heuristics to measure output errors and then train the networks weights via a plethora of different methods (back prop, GAN etc). These weights can then be used as a solver for novel problems.

For what it's worth, I don't think an NN would be a good approach to generate a solver for travelling sales man problem. You would be far better off just using a common graph search algorithm..